# password encrypt in php

Tags: php, mysql

i'm building pure php web application 
and i'm currently using md5 method to encrypt user password 
i want to know what is the best method to  encrypt  password in pure php application

Comment: never use md5 !!!! its unsafe since 2012!!

Comment: Use BCrypt with PHP's password hashing functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php.

Comment: also remember that php's `password_hash()` is a one-way hashing algorithm. In lay man's terms, means you can't decrypt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // Authenticated.
    if (password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
        // Rehash, update database.
    }
}
```

[More info](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016)